# Got a dpkg warning during update

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg

After doing a standard update-upgrade I got 2 warning messages highlighted in orange color:

```
dpkg: warning: unable to delete the old directory '/var/lib/ubuntu-advantage': Directory not empty
dpkg: warning: unable to delete the old directory '/etc/ubuntu-advantage': Directory not empty
```

Does anyone know what this thing is should I just leave it or do I need to remove something??

Comment: I noticed the same thing, and I've just let it be. I don't think it's an issue.

Comment: ... you can leave it :-) ... That is a result of either the presence of non package standard files inside those directories like e.g. user added files, old saved copies of configuration files or in rare cases an incompatible post-install script in the updated package.